# (Python) change the content of file into lower case

Tags: python

I want to change the content of words in the file.
To change it to lower case.
I tried the code below however the code seems do not respond with the action.

```
def preprocessing(input_file):

    my_handle = open(input_file, 'r')
    input_file='aba.tok'

    for line in my_handle:  
        line = line.lower()    
    my_handle.close()
```

Comment: You reference input_file before it is declared. That isn't right. Also, you don't output or return anything.

Comment: But I tried to move input_file before my_handle, there is no responses at all.

Comment: There is no response, because you haven't provided any output from the function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
def preprocessing(input_file="aba.tok"):
    data = open(input_file).read()
    my_handle = open(input_file,"w")
    my_handle.write(data.lower())
    my_handle.close()
```

You need to work in your on python skills there are some serious mistakes in the code and you need to learn about files I/O modes, I recommend you to start [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)

Comment: why can't I add input_file='aba.tok' ?

Comment: If you want it to be the default parameter value you can define the function like that def preprocessing(input_file="aba.tok"): I have updated the answer

Comment: I use Pycharm and I put the file in the Pycharm project. The file did not chage to what I want. I do not know if the file put in the wrong sapce.

Comment: your code cannot run. data variable could not be manipulated in to lower case.

Comment: The code is working, clearly, you have entered the wrong path of the file!

Comment: Put the file in desktop and give the function the full path to it and I tried the code even with knowing that it's working and guess what it worked, of course.

Comment: If this answered your question, mark it